# Один адаптер на все варианты парсинга

Tags: android, парсер, jsoup, retrofit2

Делаю парсинг нескольких сайтов. Для запросов использую Retrofit2

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://www...")
                .addConverterFactory(PageAdapter.FACTORY)
                .client(client)
                .build();
```

Адаптер

```
    class PageAdapter implements Converter<ResponseBody, Page> {
        public static final Converter.Factory FACTORY = new Converter.Factory() {

 @Override
 public Converter<ResponseBody, ?> responseBodyConverter(Type type, Annotation[] annotations, Retrofit retrofit) {
                if (type == Page.class) return new PageAdapter();
                return null;
            }
        };

        @Override
        public Page convert(ResponseBody responseBody) throws IOException {
            Document document = Jsoup.parse(responseBody.string());
            Element value = document.getElementById("m_img");
            String content = value.absUrl("src");
            return new Page(content);
        }

    }
```

Page

```
class Page {
    public String content;

    public Page(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }
}
```

Как можно написать один адаптер,для всех вариантов парсинга которые отличались  бы  разными тегам(с одного текст,с другого урл и т.д.),то есть метод convert.(Element value)

В итоге должно получится ,примерно, так

```
 public void onResponse(Call<Site1> call, Response<Site1> response) {
                            Log.i("test1",response.body().content1);

                        }
...
 public void onResponse(Call<Site2> call, Response<Site2> response) {
                            Log.i("test2",response.body().content2);

                        }
```

Comment: А зачем вам вообще `Retrofit` если есть `Jsoup` =/

Comment: Напишите свой `RetroJsoup` :D

Comment: @Flippy еще делаю POST запросы, отсылаю то что спарсил

Comment: Вроде все понятно, но непонятно. Можно поподробнее суть объяснить?

Comment: Вам нужно инструкции по парсингу применять разные?

Comment: @Flipy да:распарсил-отправил-получил-распарсил....

Comment: Даже не знаю.. Может какой-то `Runnable` для каждой задачи создавать?